# unexpected behavior js for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, wordsearch

I am creating a wordsearch generator with JavaScript I created the function that places the word, it is working as expected but I created a list of words to add them to the wordsearch in a forloop the problem it's that it just adds one word

this is the code I wrote

```
function placeWord(p,grid) {

    for (i=0;i<p.length;i++) {

    grid[p[i][0]][p[i][1]] = p[i][2]

    }

}

function tryPlaceWord(word, grid, width, height) {

    let s = 0

    var directions = [[0,1], [1,0], [1,1]]

    var choices = [word, word.split("").reverse().join("")]

    var word = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]

    while (s<2) {

       var direction = directions[ Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)   ]

       var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * width)

       var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * height)

       var ystart = y+word.length > height ?  y-word.length:y  

       var xstart = x+word.length > width ?  x-word.length:x

       var positions = []

       for (i=0;i<word.length;i++) {

           if (xstart < 0) {

           break

           }

       if (ystart<0) {

           break

      }

          var xpos = xstart + i * direction[1]

      var ypos = ystart +i * direction[0]

      pos = grid[ypos][xpos]

      if (pos == "*" || pos == word[i]) {

        positions[i] = [ypos, xpos, word[i]]

    } else {

        positions.length = 0

        break

    }

       }

       if (positions.length == word.length) {

       placeWord(positions,grid)

       console.log(positions)

       return true 

       }

    s+=1

    }

}

function show(grid) {

    for (i=0;i<grid.length;i++) {

    console.log(grid[i].join(" "));

    }

}

function makeGrid(width, height) {

    var grid = []

    for (i=0;i<height;i++) {

    grid[i] = []

    for (y=0;y<width;y++) {

        grid[i][y] = "*"

    }

    }

    return grid

}

function main() {

    var width = 15

    var height = 15

    var grid = makeGrid(width, height)

    var words = ["alexander", "camila", "pedro", "luis", "maria"]

    for (i=0;i<words.length;i++) {  

    console.log(words[i])

        tryPlaceWord(words[i],grid,width, height)

    }

    show(grid)

}

main()
```

any help would be really appreciated

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

Gooood afernoon

TLDR; You need to initialize your for-loop counters with the [let-keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

---

when you write

```js
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) { /* do something */ }
```

it get's interpreted as

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { /* do something */ }}
```

A simple example of why that is annoying in your case is becase var is stored at the outer most [lexical scope](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-lexical-scope-tutorial/).

```js
console.log(i) // undefined

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { /* do something */ }

console.log(i) // 5

// i = 5 here, so the next loop reads that '5 < 5' -> false, so it doesn't execute

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { /* do something */ }
```

when using let `i` does not get hoisted and is bound to the [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) of the for-loop

```js
console.log(i) // undefined

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { /* do something */ }

console.log(i) // undefined

// the next for loop initializes i to 0 again
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: thanks very much, it fixed the problem, I will look into the information you shared in the link.

Comment: Hey man no worries, your logic seemed to work fine, just some (imo) weird JS behaviour